# Limited rotation?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I can't seem to rotate the highlighted part, if I try to do so with R it will rotate the whole object.

Can someone tell me a way to only rotate the highlighted part?

(Also thanks for the helpful replies on my previous question!)

Comment: You have proportional editing enabled, the icon with the blue circle on the bottom of 3D view screen

Answer (score 1):

You have to *turn off* [Proportional Editing](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional%20editing), just press <kbd>O</kbd> key.